# Java - Looping main args

Tags: java, loops, args

I have the following parameter in command line:

> -Conf file.txt -dirs folder1 folder2 folder3.....

I am trying to know how many folders there are + print them out, I know the folders start from args[3] (args 2 is "-dirs").

I tried using a for loop to loop from args[3] until args array ends, was supposed to print out the folders one by one:

```
for(int c=3;c<args.length;c++) {
System.out.println (args[c]); }
```

But it does not work.

Comment: In future, please specify how it "does not work". You have told us the expected behaviour, but can you give the output when it runs? Otherwise, as we do not read minds, "does not work" could mean it prints "wombats".

Answer (score 1):

You got the condition backwards. It should be `c<args.length` :

```
for(int c=3;c<args.length;c++) {
    System.out.println (args[c]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=3; i<args.length; i++)
  System.out.println(args[i]);
```

A different kind of solution(but it prints all the elements):

```
for (String s: args) 
 System.out.println(s);
```

Some words about args in java:

In Java args contains the supplied [command-line arguments](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/command-args.html) as an array of String objects.

In other words, if you run your program as java MyProgram one two then args will contain ["one", "two"].

Comment: This person doesn't want to print the first three args, but your code does - this isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: If you _really_ want to use that kind of for loop (inefficiently), you can do `for (String s : Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 3, args.length)) {/*...*/}`.